# String interpolation, string formatting and null coalescing operator at once

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting, string-interpolation

I need this:
If the following formatted value is null, display N/A. Otherwise, display the formatted value. It needs to be with string interpolation. I tried to do something like nested interpolation:

```
$"{$"({someValue:N0})" ?? "N/A" }"
```

but the result is just empty string.
Using .NET 7.

Comment: String interpolation will never yield `null` so the `?? "N/A"` part is completely superfluous.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense I guess. Could you suggest an alternative way to format a string with ?? or is it off the table entirely?

Comment: Alternative way without interpolation: `someValue?.ToString("N0") ?? "N/A"`

Comment: @madreflection Well, technically a [custom string interpolation handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/interpolated-string-handler) can do anything, including returning `null`

Comment: What is the type of your `someValue`? "N0" format usually suitable for numerics, which are value types and can't be null (if not marked as Nullable). So null-check looks a bit redundant.

Comment: @Ed'ka: Edge case. Technically, you're right because it could yield null in the same way that you can set a non-nullable string to null with `!`, but I'd say that any interpolated string handler that yields `null` is broken because it didn't interpolate to a `string` instance. The interpolated string handlers implemented in the BCL don't yield `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue here is that $"({someValue:N0})" will never evaluate to null becasue of the () outside the {}. What I would do here is the following:

`(someValue == null ? "N/A" : $"({someValue:N0})"`

This is essentially an inline if/else statement, where the portion before the `?` is the condition, the first string (before the `:`) is what you get if the condition is true, and the second string is what you get if the condition is false.